# Logical && statement

Tags: objective-c, c, scanf

I want to understand why following code is not work as it should:

```
 char c;

 NSLog(@"Enter a single character: ");
 scanf("%c", &c);

 if (c >= '0' &&  c <= '9') {
     NSLog(@"It's a digit");
 }
```

When I enter a number between 0 and 9 I get correct output - "It's a digit". But when I enter something like 197 I get the same output. But in logical operator (&&) both conditions should met. Why does it evaluate to true when the number is larger than 9?

By the way, if case any of you don't know, `scanf` allows you to input something in the Xcode console or in the terminal.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after scanning the variable and inspect its value. What do you think it's value is?

Comment: You're only reading a single `char`, so when you enter `197`, `c` will be `'1'`.

Comment: @MightyPork It's more about C than it is about Objective-C. It doesn't really matter that the OP is using NSLog to write to the console. That's not where the problem lies

Comment: @MightyPork @EvgeniyKleban If the OP would use `puts`, this would be a C question, right? The problem has to do with `char`s and `scanf`, which is C.

Comment: Anyway, the [tag:scanf] tag is probably more relevant than either of the language tags.

Comment: Good job on removing the language tag, now you killed the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Guys, this should be tagged  - I am updating to use both tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char c`, implies `scanf("%c", &c)` can only read a single character into char variable `c`. Hence input `197` will read as `1` in to `c`, making logical `&&` true.  [Look at this compilation](http://ideone.com/RUFxQU)

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading the "1".  And this is within your range.